# Show That a 2D Linear Transform $ T \left( \cdot \right) $ Is Homogeneous

Tags: discrete-signals, linear-systems, 2d

By my understanding, a transform T is homogeneous if T[0] = 0.

Then to prove that a linear transformation is homogeneous we say that:

T[a*x(n1, n2) + b*x(n1, n2)] = a*T[x(n1, n2)] + b*T[x(n1, n2)]

What I want to know is the difference between the following two proofs and which one is "more correct" or is there perhaps a even better answer?

let x(n1, n2) = 0

then we know that,

a*x(n1,n2)- a*x(n1,n2) = 0,
T[a*x(n1, n2) + a*x(n1, n2)] = a*T[x(n1, n2)] + a*T[x(n1, n2)] = 0

VS

Simply showing that both sides are equal to 0 if x(n1, n2) = 0 through algebra.

On a side note, can someone also comment on why we would even care if a transformation is homogeneous vs heterogeneous? In reference to a transformation applied onto a 2D signal (such as an image transformation).

Maybe the better question to ask would be to prove if a transformation is heterogeneous, is it linear? (if so can someone help me define what it means for a transformation to be heterogeneous? Like how a homogeneous transform means T[0] = 0.

Comment: I have a follow up question, according to this link on [convolution](http://www.songho.ca/dsp/convolution/convolution.html#convolution_2d), convolution has a requirement that the system "must be" linear and time/space invariant. Does this mean we can not use the conventional convolution on a heterogeneous signal, but we can for a homogeneous signal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea here is that any Linear Operator is Homogeneous though not every Homogeneous Operator is Linear.

The classic proof indeed is to build the zero term as a sum (Difference) of 2 other elements in the domain. Then use Linearity to show it must be zero:

$$ T \left( 0, 0 \right) = T \left( {m}_{1} - {m}_{1}, {n}_{1} - {n}_{1} \right) = T \left( {m}_{1}, {n}_{1} \right) - T \left( {m}_{1}, {n}_{1} \right) = 0 $$

> Maybe the better question to ask would be to prove if a transformation is heterogeneous, is it linear?

As I wrote above, if an operator is heterogeneous is must not be linear.

Think of the simplest Linear Operator in 1D: $ T \left( x \right) = a x $. Clearly it is a linear function and indeed homogeneous.
Let's look on Affine Function: $ T \left( x \right) = a x + b $. Usually this is also called Linear Function while it is not unless $ b = 0 $. Why? It is not heterogeneous.

It is easy to see that $ T \left( {x}_{1} - {x}_{1} \right) \neq T \left( {x}_{1} \right) - T \left( {x}_{1} \right) $.